# Switch Case not able to use this reference

Tags: javascript

I have a switch case that I cannot break out of using 'this' if I put a straight forward string it works just fine. I can use this.translation.User anywhere else and it resolves no problem. Any ideas?

```
switch(test){
   case "User":
      return this.translation.User
      break;
   case "System":
      return this.translation.System
      break;
}
return "";
```

Comment: We can't figure out what `this` is or is supposed to be with this snippet. Give us the function that holds this code, as well as the line in which you call that function

Comment: there is no (sub) scope with in `switch`. The problem is `this` being visible in whatever context your `switch` is in

Comment: Crayon Violent I can declare a variable inside of the switch similar to this?   `var scope = this;` then use `return scope.translation.System` ?

Comment: umm if you are using `this` as a randomly declared variable, e.g. `var this='foobar';` don't do that. Use a different namespace; `this` is a special variable

Comment: well yes, you can do `var scope=this;` and then use like `scope.translation.User`. Or, you can just use `this` to begin with. So now we're back to the issue of what context the `switch` is actually in

Comment: I feel I may be out of scope since the switch is inside of a function and the translation is defined at a global level.

Comment: @pcproff - It would help to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the keyword ***[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)***.

`this` is going to refer to the context the code is executing under. `this` will refer to the window, or global context, unless it is inside of a defined context such as an object, a new function, or event callback.

Make sure you are in the correct context for accessing the translation you are looking for.